# How do I read an input file, modify its contents and save the result to an output file with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

In my project I have an input file like in this program :

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var str = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8');
```

But I had to use this command in my terminal :

`cat input.txt | ./prog.sh > result.txt`

Can you help me please, because I didn't find how can I code a general input file in JS with this kind of command in the terminal ?

Comment: It appears as though you are trying to take the contents of `input.txt`, manipulate it in some way, and then take the results and overwrite `result.txt`. Is that correct?

Comment: Excatly @holaymolay

Comment: So have you got a solution please ? @holaymolay

Comment: Ok i'll post an answer

Comment: I have the same problem @holaymolay, you already post your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The following code permit to take every name type of document at the entry of the terminal command, this code works well :

#!/usr/bin/env node

```
let chunk = "";

process.stdin.on("data", data => {
    chunk += data.toString();
});

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
    chunk.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
        process.stdout.write(
        s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy \n'
        : s === 'alicia'
           ? 'girl\n'
           : s === 'cookie'
               ? 'dog \n'
               : 'unknown \n');
    });
});
```

We can execute it correctly with the following command :
`cat input.txt | /prog2.js > result.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This should completely overwrite the result.txt file or create it anew if it doesn't exist.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const inputFile = "./input.txt"; 
const outputFile = "./result.txt";

var str = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8').toString();

var prog = (fileStr) => {
  let modifiedStr = fileStr.trim() + " !!!modified!!!"; // do something to modify the string
  return modifiedStr;
};

let fileContents = prog(str);

fs.writeFile(outputFile, fileContents, function(err){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('string saved to ' + outputFile);
});
```

Comment: in this case the input file, need always to be called "input.txt", I don't know how can we code in JS in order to take all type of input, with different name of input, how can we code that please, have you got an idea?

Comment: @cpeUser2018 yes, but you should have been more clear about what you need. Are random files uploaded to a folder? Are they always `.txt` files? What do I need to know about where the input files are located?

Comment: @cpeUser2018 also, will you want to run each file in the folder through prog()?